# Calling setpgid/setsid when spawning external programs

Tags: linux, process, posix, process-group

When running an external program from my code, I have these three options:

1. Do nothing after `fork()`. The external program will be in its parent's process group.
2. Call `setpgid(0, 0)` or similar, so the external program will get its own process group.
3. Call `setsid()`, which also separates the external program from its parent's controlling tty.

Which of the above behaviors is correct in which situations?

For example, I'm seeing a funny behavior using vim and gnome-open:

1. I run `:!gnome-open somefile.pdf`, which starts a PDF viewer and returns immediately.
2. I then run, for example, `:!cat`, and while cat is running, send a `SIGQUIT` using `CTRL-\`.

The PDF viewer crashes. This happens because both vim and gnome-open seem to spawn their subprocesses in their own process group.

It might be too obscure to be called a bug, but still I wonder who's at fault here: is there any reason for vim or gnome-open not to call `setpgid` after forking, like a shell would do? Would it make more sense for `gnome-open` to call `setsid` instead to separate the X application from the terminal it was launched from? (I find it strange that GLib doesn't offer a standard and cross-platform way to do such things.)

Comment: Just curious: What's the PDF viewer?

Comment: It's okular, but I don't think it matters much.